# How to change page after login button click ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making a login page on ReactJS and I would like to load a other page if the login is succesful. I am also using Firebase and react router)

This is a part of my "*Login.js*":

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Fire from "../firebase config/Firebase"

function Login(){


    const Login_Submit = () => {
        Fire.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // ...
            console.log(errorCode + errorMessage)
        });


        Fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (user) {
              // User is signed in.
              // This is where I want to load a other page
            } else {
              // No user is signed in.
            }
        });
    }


    return(

        <div>
                <div>
                    <form className = "form-username">
                        <input className = "username" type="email" placeholder = "Email" value = {email} onChange = {refresh_mail}/>
                    </form>

                    <form className = "form-password">
                        <input className = "password" type="password" placeholder = "Password" value = {password} onChange = {refresh_password}/>
                    </form>

                    <div className = "buttons">
                        <button className = "button is-primary login" onClick = {Login_Submit}>Login</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

    )


}


export default Login
```

I am a beginner on ReactJS so thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first you will need react router dom, after which you will destructure Redirect off it.

Like this.

```js
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then you will write a condition to redirect to a page, if user is signed in (based on the state of course).

Something like this.

```js
  render(){
    return (
    <div >
    <Header />
    <Switch>
     <Route exact path='/' component={Homepage} />
     <Route path='/shop' component={ShopPage} />
     <Route exact path='/checkout' component={CheckoutPage} />
     <Route exact path='/signin' 
                 //this part to be precise
                  render={() => 
                    this.props.currentUser ? 
                    (<Redirect to='/' />) : 
                    (<SignInAndSignUpPage />)} 
      />
  </Switch>
    </div>
  );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

React does not have "pages". The idea is more to "show" or "hide" components, this gives the user a page/view impression.

The easiest way to achieve routing in React is to use a declarative router library like react router especially for more complex apps.

try Link component of react-router-dom and pass to as a path to it wherever you want to redirect on onClick.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


<Link to={'/Components'}>
  <button > Click Me </button>
</Link>
const {Link, BrowserRouter} = window.ReactRouterDOM
function App(){
  return (
  <BrowserRouter>
      <button><Link to='/abc' target='_blank'> Click Me  </Link></button>

    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do. Use react router to lets say: `localhost/login` (login.js) and load  `localhost/menu` (menu.js)  if the login is successful on firebase. But how can I do it ?